# Neo4j Cypher: Get neighbours for variable length path given condition, skip those that do not meet condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a problem, and I've abstracted it as such:

```
(a)-[:PREVIOUS]->(b)-[:PREVIOUS]->(c)-[:PREVIOUS]->(d)-[:PREVIOUS]->(e)-[:PREVIOUS]->(f)
(b)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: 'Red'})
(c)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: 'Red'})
(d)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: 'Red'})
(e)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: 'Blue'})
(f)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: 'Red'})
```

Note,

```
(:Colour {Name: 'Red'})
```

is unique and connected to many nodes e.g.

```
(a)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: Red})<-[:IS]-(b)
```

but only

```
(e)-[:IS]->(:Colour {Name: Blue})
```

I'm trying to construct a query where the data is related as shown in the above graph. What I want to do is obtain a node and its 2 previous neighbours. However, there are conditions:

1. I only want to return neighbours that share the same "IS" property.
2. If there is a neighbour with a different "IS" property, skip it.
3. If a node has less than 2 previous neighbours, then return 1 or 0 neighbours.

I've made attempts at this but can't produce the below output. The COMPLETE output for the above graph, should look like this:

```
a, b, c
b, c, d
c, d, f
d, f
e
f
```

Note that for node (c), we get back (d), (f) and skip (e) as it is blue; (d) should have similar behaviour. (e) returns itself only, as it is the only blue node. Does anyone know if there is an easy solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each of those currently non-labeled nodes has a label you can use for the query (I'm just going to use :Node here), this should work:

```
// for each node, get its color
MATCH (n:Node)-[:IS]->(myColor)
// find paths to all previous nodes (where the colors match)
// this includes the starting node, which has distance 0
MATCH path = (n)-[:PREVIOUS*0..]->(prev)
WHERE (prev)-[:IS]->(myColor)
// for each node, order its previous nodes by distance
WITH n, prev
ORDER BY length(path) ASC
// grab first three closest (first will always be the node itself)
WITH n, collect(prev)[..3] as prevs
RETURN prevs
ORDER BY size(prevs) DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right path to my problem. My dataset is far more complex than this (so didn't test solution), but I also believe it solves the problem I stated. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly (aside from the speed)! Verified it on my data, does exactly what I want as stated in the question.